# How to expose SQL Server temporal table history records via ASP.NET Core Web API ODataController

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, microsoft.aspnetcore.odata

How does one expose a SQL Server temporal table's history data via an ASP.NET Core Web API ODataController accessing its data from an Entity Framework Core repository?

I am encountering "invalid OData path template" warnings from the Web API project and the controller responds with a JSON entity array rather than with an OData JSON object.

The following artifacts illustrate the issue.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Etsy.Tags 
(
    Id        INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    Name      Etsy.TagType NOT NULL,
    ValidFrom DATETIME2(2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
    ValidTo   DATETIME2(2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Tags_Id PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id ASC),
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME(ValidFrom, ValidTo)
) ON PRIMARY WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = History.EtsyTags));
GO

ALTER TABLE Etsy.Tags 
    ADD CONSTRAINT DF__Tags__ValidFrom 
        DEFAULT (GETUTCDATE()) FOR ValidFrom;
GO

ALTER TABLE Etsy.Tags 
    ADD CONSTRAINT DF__Tags__ValidTo   
        DEFAULT (CONVERT(DATETIME2(2), '9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999')) FOR ValidTo;
GO

CREATE TABLE History.EtsyTags 
(
    Id        INT          NOT NULL,
    Name      Etsy.TagType NOT NULL,
    ValidFrom DATETIME2(2) NOT NULL,
    ValidTo   DATETIME2(2) NOT NULL
) ON PRIMARY;
```

```cs
public class Etsy_TagsController : ODataController 
{
    private readonly WordArtDbContext _context;

    public Etsy_TagsController(WordArtDbContext context) 
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    [HttpGet("Etsy_Tags({id})/History")]
    public IQueryable<Etsy_Tag_ValidBoth> Get_Etsy_Tag_History(int id) 
    {
        return _context.Etsy_Tags.TemporalAll()
            .Where(_ => _.Id == id)
            .Select(_ => new Etsy_Tag_ValidBoth {
                Id = _.Id,
                Name = _.Name,
                ValidFrom = EF.Property<DateTime>(_, "ValidFrom"),
                ValidTo = EF.Property<DateTime>(_, "ValidTo")
            });
    }
}
```

```cs
public partial class WordArtDbContext : DbContext 
{
    public WordArtDbContext(DbContextOptions<WordArtDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public virtual DbSet<Etsy_Tag> Etsy_Tags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new Configurations.Etsy_TagConfiguration());
        OnModelCreatingGeneratedProcedures(modelBuilder);
        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

```cs
public partial class Etsy_Tag 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
    public virtual ICollection<Etsy_ListingTag> Etsy_ListingTags { get; set; } = default;
}

public partial class Etsy_Tag_ValidFrom : Etsy_Tag 
{
    [ReadOnly(isReadOnly: true)]
    public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
}

public class Etsy_Tag_ValidBoth : Etsy_Tag_ValidFrom 
{
    [ReadOnly(isReadOnly: true)]
    public required DateTime ValidTo { get; init; }
}
```

```cs
public partial class Etsy_TagConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Etsy_Tag> 
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Etsy_Tag> entity) 
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PK_Tags_Id");
        entity.ToTable("Tags", "Etsy")
              .ToTable(tb => tb.IsTemporal(ttb => {
                  ttb.UseHistoryTable("EtsyTags", "History");
                  ttb.HasPeriodStart("ValidFrom").HasColumnName("ValidFrom");
                  ttb.HasPeriodEnd("ValidTo").HasColumnName("ValidTo");
              }));
        entity.HasIndex(e => e.Name, "UX_Tags_Name_Unique").IsUnique();
        entity.Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(20);
        OnConfigurePartial(entity);
    }

    partial void OnConfigurePartial(EntityTypeBuilder<Etsy_Tag> entity);
}
```

`WordArt\WordArt.Api\EdmModelBuilder.g.cs`:

```cs
public static class EdmModelBuilder 
{
    public static IEdmModel GetEdmModel() 
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        EntityTypeConfiguration<Etsy_Tag> etsyTagEntityTypeConfiguration = builder.EntitySet<Etsy_Tag>("Etsy_Tags").EntityType;
        builder.EntitySet<Etsy_Tag_ValidBoth>("Etsy_Tags_History");
        FunctionConfiguration etsyTagFunctionConfiguration = etsyTagEntityTypeConfiguration.Function("History");
        etsyTagFunctionConfiguration.Parameter<int>("id");
        etsyTagFunctionConfiguration.ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<Etsy_Tag_ValidBoth>("Etsy_Tags_History");
        etsyTagFunctionConfiguration.IsComposable = true;
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
}
```

The ASP.NET Core Web API project throws this warning at startup:

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.Conventions.AttributeRoutingConvention[0]
      The path template 'Etsy_Tags({id})/History' on the action 'Get_Etsy_Tag_History' in controller 'Etsy_Tags' is not a valid OData path template. Resource not found for the segment 'History'.
```

And the endpoint doesn't return an OData response. Instead, it just returns an array of `Etsy_Tag_ValidBoth` entities.

Request: `GET {{Api}}/Etsy_Tags(41)/History`

Response:

```json
[
  {
    "ValidTo": "9999-12-31T23:59:59.99",
    "ValidFrom": "2023-08-12T22:54:11.11",
    "Id": 41,
    "Name": "Motivational Graphic"
  },
  // ...
]
```

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.1" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Project>
```

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData" Version="8.2.4" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// ...
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options => {
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
})
    .AddOData(options => options
        .Select()
        .Filter()
        .OrderBy()
        .Expand()
        .Count()
        .EnableQueryFeatures()
        .AddRouteComponents(routePrefix: "", model: EdmModelBuilder.GetEdmModel())
    );
// ...
var app = builder.Build();
// ...
app.UseODataQueryRequest();
// ...
app.Run();
```

What tweaks are required to avoid the "is not a valid OData path template" warning at launch and get the Web API controller to respond with OData?

I have very long threads of interaction with *ChatGPT* and *GitHub CoPilot* attempting to resolve this issue. Suffice it; no suggestion so far as led to a solution.